# Cezve doesn't leak with cold water in it, leaks after heating

Tags: coffee, heat

I have a [cezve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cezve) I bought some time ago. I've tried making some coffee with it, and after about 30 seconds of heating on the stove, it starts to leak (dripping one by one). Is there any way to fix this, or does it have to be thrown away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to find the crack (presumably there is a crack which is tight when cold, but opens with heating due to thermal expansion) and then you would need to fix it, or have someone else fix it, with a food safe (lead and cadmium free) solder or brazing material. Whether this is economical or not depends on many factors:

- Can you do it yourself, do you know somone who can, or will you need to hire a professional
- Are professionals who do "pot and pan repair" easily found in your area or not?
- How much does a new coffeepot (cezve) cost relative to the cost of getting it fixed?